# 90s or 80s Sci-Fi movie about an artifical female

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, artificial-intelligence

I have been looking for a movie which I watched probably in 1990s.

In the movie, there were two scientists, one specialized in hardware (human-like robot body), the other one specialized in software (artificial intelligence).

The latter one created an artificial female whom attracted him so much that he decided to bring her into reality. Then he seeked help from his colleague who was working on hardware, and promised him something good.

I have forgot the rest of this story, probably something like that this artificial female eventually got out of computer screen (into reality), then killed both her creators, etc.

It has been **correctly answered**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuosity

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange!  Please take our [tour] and read through the [FAQ], and I'd also suggest you look over [ask].  You could improve this question by saying where (geographically and on what media) you saw the movie, in what language (and whether it was dubbed or subtitled), whether it was live action or animated, or any other details -- even a description of the artificial character might help.  Please [edit] the additional information into your question.

Comment: Weird Science matches this, except for her killing them

Comment: @Valorum Chet....and maybe Grandma and Grandpa....

Comment: @Valorum Confirmed that it is not 'Weird Science' in which two teenage boys magically converted a toy into human.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a couple of scenes from Virtuosity (1995).

In the first scene, Clyde Reilly (the hardware expert played by Kevin O'Connor) is interacting with Sheila 3.2, a virtual woman AI (played by Heidi Schanz) created by Darryl Lindenmeyer (the software expert played by Stephen Spinella). Sheila 3.2 begs Clyde to enter the virtual world so they can copulate. Lindenmeyer then suggests that it might be better if they use Clyde's new nano-tech robot to build Sheila 3.2 "in the flesh". Clyde tells Lindenmeyer to bring Sheila 3.2's AI character module to his lab. Lindenmeyer then replaces Sheila 3.2's AI character module with the module of Sid 6.7, a vicious, psychopathic murdering AI (played by Russell Crowe) and heads off to Clyde's lab.

In the next scene in Clyde's lab, Clyde shows off a nano-tech snake. He cuts off the tail of the snake to demonstrate how the nano-tech robot can regenerate itself using glass. He then removes the snake's character module to show that removal of the module results in the "death" of the nano-tech robot. Clyde takes Lindenmeyer over to a nano-tech incubation chamber and asks for Sheila's module. He drops the module into the nano-tech fluid and watches the process begin before closing the chamber up.

This is a great sci-fi film starring Denzel Washington and Russell Crowe and an amazing supporting cast listed above and including Louise Fletcher, William Forsythe, William Fichtner, Traci Lords, and a very young Kaley Cuoco. While the CG is a bit dated, it has a great deal of practical effects, so the film really looks good even with the CG aside.

Comment: Just watched it. That is the one I have been looking for. You have amazing knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help out.